# Mutiple config files in one common InstallShield file

Tags: installshield-2016

I have multiple install shield files for different environments like Test, QA and Prod. I need to create one `Master.ism` file in which I want to create configurations like QA, Prod and Test. `Master.ism` file will contain the common setting and all the sub config files will contain specific setting. At the time of build `Master.ism` will take the required config file and will create `.exe` accordingly.

The benefit of change I want one common change there no need to change all the files.

Comment: Are you trying to build three nearly identical installers from a single project, where the differences are a matter of "configuration"? What do the differences look like - each gets a different copy of a config file, a different value in a registry key, or something else?

Comment: Yes, you are correct Michael. Actually I want one main installer file which will have all the common settings like Company name, certificate and different config files like qa and prod in which some specific changes will have. During building the exe I want to take common settings from main installer files and specific changes from the child config like qa or prod. So that if there is any change required like any dll update I will do only in main installer file not in all.

Comment: It will be really appreciate if anyone suggest something on this whether it is possible with Install Shield or not. Can we achieve this with WIX..